# TypeError: in typeassert in Julia 1.6.3

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. I am working on a Julia package which the writer is not available.

This is the part of the code where I have a problem with:

```
function find_partition(model::Model, ms)
    ps = Dict{Z3Expr,Vector{Int}}()
    for (i, m) in enumerate(ms)
        mval = Z3.eval(model, m, false)
        println(ps)
        println(mval)
        println(typeof(mval))
        if haskey(ps, mval)
            push!(ps[mval], i)
        else
            push!(ps, mval=>Int[i])
        end
    end
    values(ps)
end
```

Here is the output:

```
Dict{Z3.Expr, Vector{Int64}}()
1.0
Z3.ExprAllocated
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected UInt64, got a value of type UInt32
Stacktrace:
  [1] hashindex(key::Z3.ExprAllocated, sz::Int64)
    @ Base ./dict.jl:169
  [2] ht_keyindex(h::Dict{Z3.Expr, Vector{Int64}}, key::Z3.ExprAllocated)
    @ Base ./dict.jl:284
  [3] haskey(h::Dict{Z3.Expr, Vector{Int64}}, key::Z3.ExprAllocated)
    @ Base ./dict.jl:550
  [4] find_partition(model::Z3.ModelAllocated, ms::Vector{Z3.ExprAllocated})
    @ Absynth.NLSat ~/Desktop/faoc/Absynth/src/nlsat/cfinitesolver.jl:101
```

I tried following it and found out that somewhere inside `dict.jl` in Julia, there are such lines

```
sz = length(h.keys)
...
index = hashindex(key, sz)
```

And this is the hashindex written somewhere in dict.jl:

```
hashindex(key, sz) = (((hash(key)::UInt % Int) & (sz-1)) + 1)::Int
```

It seems that the version of Z3 used in this package is not compatible with the current version of Julia. I am not sure if this package was working in the beginning at all.

Is there any quick fix to this? Like rewriting this part of the code:

```
if haskey(ps, mval)
     push!(ps[mval], i)
else
     push!(ps, mval=>Int[i])
```

in a way that this won't happen? I tried writing like `merge!(ps,Dict(mval=>Int[i]))` but it's eventually reaching this hashindex function again.
If I install the older versions of Julia, would it be possible to solve this issue or the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Related github issue: https://github.com/ahumenberger/Z3.jl/issues/15

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but you can try `ps[mval] = [i]`. This is also more idiomatic.

Comment: I tracked down the exact commit to `dict.jl` (#37084) that added the `UInt64` type assertion to `hashindex` (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/37084). I never worked with `Z3.jl` so I would be interested in knowing why a `UInt32` is used for hashing, just seems like an odd choice.